# Need jQuery menu to slide down on first hover and hovering on other menus just show it's div and no need of slide down effect

Tags: jquery

Need jQuery menu to slide down on first hover and hovering on other menus just show it's div and no need of slide down effect. Here I created 5 containers and made it to slide down on hover. The slide down function is applying to every div. But I need slide down function only for first hover state (it may be any main menu hover) and then hovering on other menu just show the div without any slide down effect. (i.e) the container must be fixed and the content inside it has to be changed.

`jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/N8KWG/2/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, solution is for home menu only, you will need to add if condition in rest of all hover events.

```
$('.home').hover(function(){

    if($('.container-2,.container-3,.container-4,.container-5,.container-6,.container-7,.container-8').is(":visible"))
    {
        $('.container-2,.container-3,.container-4,.container-5,.container-6,.container-7,.container-8').hide();
        $('.container-1').show();
    }

 $('.container-1').slideDown(750);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="primary-menu">
    <ul class="primary-menu-heading">
        <li class="home"> <a href="#"> Home </a> 
        </li>
        <li class="products"> <a href="#"> Products </a> 
        </li>
        <li class="payments"> <a href="#"> Category </a> 
        </li>
        <li class="ways"> <a href="#"> Sub-Products </a> 
        </li>
        <li class="offers"> <a href="#"> Latest Offers </a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-home">
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container-products">
        <p>hello world</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container-payments">
        <p>hello world 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container-ways">
        <p>hello world 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container-offers">
        <p>hello world 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul li {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.primary-menu-heading li {
    float:left;
    padding-right:41px;
}
.primary-menu-heading li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000333;
    font-size:15px;
}
.container-home {
    width:500px;
    height:335px;
    margin:0;
    clear:both;
    background:#ccc;
}
.container-products {
    width:500px;
    height:335px;
    margin:0;
    clear:both;
    background:#ccc;
}
.container-payments {
    width:500px;
    height:335px;
    margin:0;
    clear:both;
    background:#ccc;
}
.container-ways {
    width:500px;
    height:335px;
    margin:0;
    clear:both;
    background:#ccc;
}
.container-offers {
    width:500px;
    height:335px;
    margin:0;
    clear:both;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.container').children().hide();

    /* need slide down effect only once i.e. on first hover (any menu it may be) and then the container to be just shown without any slide effect */

    $("ul.primary-menu-heading li").hover(function () {
        $(".container").children().hide();
        if ($(this).hasClass("home")) {
            $(".container-" + $(this).prop("class")).slideDown(750);
        } else {
            $(".container-" + $(this).prop("class")).show();
        }
    });
});
```